# Is it possible for an object to rotate and move forward at the same time?

Tags: reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

Is it possible for an object to rotate and move forward at the same time? Hi, my question revolves around the Tv show "Beyblade metal fusion". in this show they launch these spinning tops into a stadium which has a diameter of 500cm, but when they are in the stadium they are rotating at an angle and moving forward at the same time and I am optimistic to see the physics behind it. so the main focus of my question is How can an object rotate and move forward at the same time, And how an object can rotate at an angle

Comment: Do you mean like the Earth moving around the sun while rotating on its axis?

Comment: Or a bicycle wheel?

Comment: yeah like the earth moving around the sun while rotating on its axis

Comment: or a frisbee ??

Comment: not necessarily a frisbee because theirs no friction involved

Comment: But in general, how would a Beyblade change its angular momentum while spinning

Comment: There certainly is friction involved with a frisbee!

Comment: Is that friction between air

Comment: Why not have rotation _as well as_ translation at the same time?

Comment: I thought i did?  I meant that but maybe not clear in my answer.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I see your answer takes care of that. I didn't want my answer being too complicated. But you did answer simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motion of the center of mass and the rotation about the center of mass are independent of each other. In fact, this is what makes the center of mass of an object special. You define momentum and angular momentum about the center of mass and they are completely independent of each other. $$ \begin{aligned} 
\boldsymbol{p} & = m\, \boldsymbol{v}_{\rm CM} \\
\boldsymbol{L}_{\rm CM} & = \mathbf{I}_{\rm CM} \boldsymbol{\omega} 
\end{aligned} $$

<sub>Where $m$ is the mass, $\boldsymbol{v}_{\rm CM}$ is the velocity vector of the center of mass, $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is the rotational velocity vector, $\boldsymbol{p}$ is the momentum vector, $\boldsymbol{L}_{\rm CM}$ the angular momentum vector and $\mathbf{I}_{\rm CM}$ something called the rotational inertia tensor.</sub>

Now the point I was trying to make is that to measure angular momentum *at any other point* you need both angular and linear momentum $$ \boldsymbol{L} = \boldsymbol{L}_{\rm CM} + \boldsymbol{r}_{\rm CM} \times \boldsymbol{p} $$ <sub>Where $\times$ is the vector cross product, and $\boldsymbol{r}_{\rm CM}$ is the location of the center of mass relative to the measuring point.</sub>

So the center of mass is a special point in space where linear and rotational motion is decoupled from a momentum and force point of view.

Additionally, [Charle's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chasles%27_theorem_(kinematics)) states that if any point moves with velocity vector $\boldsymbol{v}$ and is part of a rotating rigid body with rotational velocity $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ then there exists an axis in space where the velocity vector on those points is either zero, or parallel to the axis. Like a football flying in space and rotating about the direction of flight. This axis is the *instant rotation axis*.

You'll find the location of the rotation axis by $$\boldsymbol{r}_{\rm RC} = \frac{ \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{v}}{\| \boldsymbol{\omega} \|^2} $$

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange!  Rotation and translation are separate processes. The energy of a translating process is $$ KE = \frac{1}{2} mv^2$$
where KE = kinetic energy and m,v are the mass and velocity of the object.
The $$E_{rotational} = \frac{1}{2} I\omega^2$$
where I = moment of inertia about axis of rotation and $\omega$ = angular velocity.

If you have ever thrown a frisbee then you realize that an object can easily spin and move forward. And that an object can spin while tilted.

Comment: @PM2Ring oh sorry. i've corrected that.  Thanks for pointing it out.